# Extended class constructed from the parent

Tags: java, oop

I am trying to implement my own File class, which extends from the java.io.File (please don't judge me :-) and I am trying to be able to construct my class by giving the java.io.File instance as follows:

```
public class File extends java.io.File {

    public File (String fileName) {
        super(fileName);
    }



    public File (java.io.File file) {
        // the problem
        super = file;
    }
    ...
}
```

My problem is that I would like to construct my class with something like `super = file` which is obviously an incorrect expression. Can you suggest how this could be done?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain *why* you're trying to do this? We might be able to suggest a better solution. super = file won't work, since there's no instance of 'super', only an instance of 'this'. I think what you want is a *wrapper*, not an extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
public File (java.io.File file) {
    super(file.getPath());
}
```

Comment: It is not that clean solution, but it does what I wanted. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You should use composition over inheritance, here's how it will look like

```
class YourFile{
  private final File thatFile;
  public YourFile(File file) {
    thatFile = file;
  }
//getter for thatFile may be here
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`Super`, like `this` is not assignable, but you seem to know that already. If I understand you correctly, you want to achieve a copy Ctor. For this, you should extract the properties of your `io.File` and construct your own `File` with that data.

Or use composition as gasan suggested. The downside of the composition is that you can't supplant usages of regular java `File` class with your own.